# Predicting user interaction with interface

Tags: classification, predictive-models

If I have a GUI with a set of buttons and I want to predict what button the user will select next based on a set of features including the previous n button clicks and other meta data (e.g. user's name), what area of ML is this?

Does this count as classification (i.e. classifying the next move) with the x classes being the x buttons and the features as mentioned above?

Comment: It's *discrete time series prediction*. As aplassard said, Markov process regression is well suited to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a classification problem. You could use something like a support vector machine or logistic regression to classify the next element based on you feature vector, but your application sounds like it may be better suited to a Hidden Markov Model, which models states and transition likelihoods between them.  The exact classification technique you use is heavily dependent on what you would like as a result of the classification process.

Comment: As a result I would like a probability for each button of the user selecting it next. 

Regarding a Hidden Markov Model, wouldn't that forget the history of button-clicks whereas I would like to use the history to help the classification

Comment: Yes it would, unless you consider some more advanced markov model.  If all you want out is a probability of each of the next outcome, then logistic regression is probably your most straightforward solution.

Comment: If this is definitely a classification problem how come it is suitable to use a regression technique?

Comment: Logistic regression is somewhat a misnomer in terms of regression problems where the output is any value.  Logistic regression produces an output on the interval [0,1] which can be interpreted as the probability of a class occurring. So you could build a logistic regressor for each of your buttons and then when determine the probability of each of the next buttons you could utilize a softmax output where you normalize the sum of the probabilities to be 1.

Comment: Thank you (unfortunately don't have enough reputation to up vote your answer). Is there a reason you chose logistic over least squares?

Comment: Ordinary Least Squares regression produces an output in the range [-Infinity,+Infinity] and you're trying to predict whether or not some class is true.  Effectively you want to predict a discrete outcome, not a continuous one.